# Using Rasters with XYZ layers in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm trying to use a raster layer that only has 1 source, a XYZ layer.

I have tried doing the following and then adding the source to the map but it yields the error below :

```
var saux = new ol.source.Raster({
        sources: [new ol.source.XYZ({
            projection: 'PIXELS',
            tileGrid: mapTileGrid,
            url: loc
        })],
        operation: function (pixels, data) {
            console.log("oops");
        }
    });
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: aj.Sd is not a function in ol.min.js:1
```

I've also tried creating the XYZ layer before and just appending it or returning the pixels data instead of the console.log but those just change the error. However if there's an error it seems to happen in ol.min.js.

My question is, how should I go about using a Raster with the XYZ source?

Comment: Try with `ol-debug.js` to get a more verbose message.